# How to change SDK Build tools path in VS2015 using Xamarin.Adroid

Tags: android, android-studio, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

According to serveral blogs, using SDK Build Tools version 24 ([link](https://releases.xamarin.com/technical-bulletin-android-sdk-build-tools-24/)) can cause/causes some weired errors. Now my question is: How can I define WHICH path to the build tools should be used?

In Android Studio, Gradle is used to build the app. Here I can modify the `build.gradle` file and define the version of build tools that should be used. But when doing the same with VS, it always takes the least version of the tools.
So is there a way to tell VS to use a specific path or tell VS to use a certain version like gradle does?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to [Build Process of Xamarin.Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/build_process/), you can find a setting named `AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion`:

> The Android SDK build-tools package provides the `aapt` and `zipalign` tools, among others. Multiple different versions of the build-tools package may be installed simultaneously. The build-tools package chosen for packaging is done by checking for and using a "preferred" build-tools version if it is present; if the "preferred" version is *not* present, then the highested versioned installed build-tools package is used.
>
> The `$(AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion)` MSBuild property contains the prefered build-tools version. The Xamarin.Android build system provides a default value in `Xamarin.Android.Common.targets`, and the default value may be overridden within youur project file to choose an alternate build-tools version, if (for example) the latest aapt is crashing out while a previous aapt version is known to work.

So, you can change the build-tool version by adding an `AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion` tag under each `PropertyGroup` of `YourProject.csproj` file like below:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>Full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>False</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>True</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
    <AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>
    <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>False</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    <AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion>24.0.3</AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: So if I understand it correctly: there is no way to set the sdk version somewhere in my VS project (settings), I have to change the *.csproj ?

Comment: `Sdk Version` can be changed under `Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings`. But to change `Sdk Build Tool Version` you have to change the `*.csproj` file.